# Startup liferay tomcat 6.1.1 ga2 sever with sqlserver database

Tags: sql-server, database, tomcat, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying now to startup a liferay 6.1.1 ga2 server with sqlserver database.
I created user and database with windows commande line "sqlcmd -S localhost" as the following:

```
1> create database liferayportal;
2> create login lrUser with password='abc123';
3> create user lrUser for login lrUser;
4> exec  sp_addrolemember 'liferayportal' , 'lrUser';
```

the portal-ext.properties:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/liferayportal
jdbc.default.username=lrUser
jdbc.default.password=abc123
```

And this is a summary of the stacktrace

```
09:28:36,657 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1][BasicResourcePool:1841] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@6245a4 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (3). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:410)

.
.
.
09:28:36,702 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0][BasicResourcePool:1841] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@c8aeb3 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (3). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:410)

.
.09:28:36,717 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#7][BasicResourcePool:1841] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@fab5b1 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (3). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:410)
.
.
.

09:28:36,743 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#4][BasicResourcePool:1841] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@12524b0 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (3). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:410)
.
.
.
```

Comment: Does your sql server service started?

Answer (score 0):

I would check whether the server has the port related to MSSQL open for remote access (normally the port is 1433) if not, you should set MSSQL to work on that port, and allow remote access and verify that your firewall allows the access to that port.